# Locate string s in vertical align div,Popper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `Popper` of `Material-UI`

```
<Popper id={"simplePopper"} open={true}  style={{backgroundColor: 'red',opacity:'0.5',width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
<div style={{height:"100%",verticalAlign: "middle", textAlign: "center"}}>
<i className="fas fa-5x fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i><br/>
Loading
</div>
</Popper>
```

I want to place `fa-spin` icon in the middle(vertically horizontally) of browser.

It place the icon in the middle of width but , stick to the top of screen.

`verticalAlign: "middle"` doesn't work.

Where should I fix??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can do one of two things:

```
#simplePopper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

or if you can't use flexbox for some reason

```
#simplePopper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#simplePopper > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

Comment: Thak you flex is import in this case.